# How to handle async data in ComponentDidUpdate?

Tags: reactjs, api, redux

I'm new to React and got some questions now.

I use componentDidUpdate to fetch data when the button is clicked. I manage the results data with redux. It's seem like componentDidUpdate is async function, because "console.log" always execute first before the fetch function is done. So I always got [] in the console the first time I clicked the button.

Suppose I have 2 actions I want to do when I clicked the button. First fetching the data, after that use that data and pass to another actions. How can I wait until the fetch data done after that the console.log is execute? Please help me.

```js
state = {
    searchClick: false,
    keyword: "pizza",
  };


  
componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (
      this.state.searchClick &&
      prevState.searchClick !== this.state.searchClick
    ) {
      // send get request to fetch data
      this.props.searchResults(this.state.keyword);

      //Update searchClick state
      this.setState({ ...this.state, searchClick: false });

      // console log the result data
      console.log(this.props.results);
    }
  }
```

Comment: `this.props.searchResults().then( ... update the state ...)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The console log always executes first because `searchResults` is async. What you need to do is returning a promise inside `searchResults`:

```js
const searchResults = (keywords) => {
 // fetch with the keywords and return the promise
 // or any promise that resolves after your search is completed
 return fetch(...);
};

componentDidUpdate(prevProps, prevState) {
    if (
      this.state.searchClick &&
      prevState.searchClick !== this.state.searchClick
    ) {
      // send get request to fetch data
      this.props.searchResults(this.state.keyword).then(() => {
        //Update searchClick state
        this.setState({ ...this.state, searchClick: false });
        // console log the result data
        console.log(this.props.results);
      });
    }
  }
```